# Flat table from parent-child hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following question that I would like to solve, I have three sql tables that contain data in reference to each other, to create a parent-child hierarchy, as in the picture below.

I attach scripts for creating tables and inserting to populate

the result I would like to have is this

[image]

The charts in my possession are:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CODENODES](
    [ID_NODE] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ID_CLASS] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CODECLASSES](
    [ID_CLASS] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
    )
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CODETREENODES](
    [ID_NODE_PARENT] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ID_NODE_CHILD] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
    )
```

The insert

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[CODENODES]
           ([ID_NODE]
           ,[ID_CLASS])
     VALUES
     ('0','0'),
    ('0688af08-352f-4a80-972e-467a8c9439e9','bac4f528-759a-432c-8fcc-1c71d0ee19fe'),
    ('13cb893d-4b92-47ee-bf44-a2113c24ef42','6f4ed138-1536-440c-9def-482cc3d7589f'),
    ('24d85424-7d0c-4e18-9034-a7dd917dbdc4','48846a26-59ba-4487-a61b-697ac77dd713'),
    ('28b7c819-da59-46cd-be78-94eba4c48e0e','758f269d-aab8-4f22-adf4-887a056e1867'),
    ('31740ea4-e40b-4aff-b06c-39a8805842a4','75da9cc3-9409-4623-9eb9-1f02db8d4148'),
    ('501c542c-37d5-4c06-b454-3e2cafdd0d4f','41bc78e9-ce68-48a2-afa4-90fb98495667'),
    ('63107405-af43-4877-963f-3d0c04bd8955','b9a2edc4-e5d0-4f32-a741-9209a5bc8c37'),
    ('6a44c65a-be52-4381-af7b-cc5a39fdd8d4','0fb7c349-5017-44cc-b4a5-e514d1b83a34'),
    ('6e5aba48-eeea-4d11-8433-c234f4e56031','2c426150-2f01-447c-842a-00be68517f7c'),
    ('77901138-4626-4e5f-867c-cb10a91f784b','e5910251-d6f0-45d5-bc14-c24dbe0d96b8'),
    ('a62ed590-725a-4cd1-b03c-34e8720e3ee3','e9848ffd-c2f0-4b33-9419-573b75425303'),
    ('b1506711-2c14-4205-9692-0c5bafe6708a','99a4a2e9-3eb0-4863-bfe1-b2e716306d23'),
    ('d8ca46e9-5665-4d1d-bbc5-ea5c1ff38fbb','c46c43c6-b57d-4fb6-846c-57fa0e8e50b4'),
    ('daea4761-6811-4ac8-bb2d-1ce3b4546f4c','15d98965-4d20-4578-9058-7b7950caeef8')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CODECLASSES]
           ([ID_CLASS]
           ,[NAME]
     VALUES
     ('0','ROOT'),
        ('0fb7c349-5017-44cc-b4a5-e514d1b83a34','AAA'),
        ('15d98965-4d20-4578-9058-7b7950caeef8','BBBB'),
        ('2c426150-2f01-447c-842a-00be68517f7c','BBB'),
        ('41bc78e9-ce68-48a2-afa4-90fb98495667','AAAA'),
        ('48846a26-59ba-4487-a61b-697ac77dd713','BB'),
        ('6f4ed138-1536-440c-9def-482cc3d7589f','B'),
        ('758f269d-aab8-4f22-adf4-887a056e1867','A'),
        ('75da9cc3-9409-4623-9eb9-1f02db8d4148','CCC'),
        ('99a4a2e9-3eb0-4863-bfe1-b2e716306d23','BBBB'),
        ('b9a2edc4-e5d0-4f32-a741-9209a5bc8c37','AA'),
        ('bac4f528-759a-432c-8fcc-1c71d0ee19fe','CCCC'),
        ('c46c43c6-b57d-4fb6-846c-57fa0e8e50b4','BB'),
        ('e5910251-d6f0-45d5-bc14-c24dbe0d96b8','BBB'),
        ('e9848ffd-c2f0-4b33-9419-573b75425303','CC')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CODETREENODES]
           ([ID_NODE_PARENT]
           ,[ID_NODE_CHILD])
     VALUES
     ('0','13cb893d-4b92-47ee-bf44-a2113c24ef42'),
    ('0','28b7c819-da59-46cd-be78-94eba4c48e0e'),
    ('13cb893d-4b92-47ee-bf44-a2113c24ef42','a62ed590-725a-4cd1-b03c-34e8720e3ee3'),
    ('13cb893d-4b92-47ee-bf44-a2113c24ef42','d8ca46e9-5665-4d1d-bbc5-ea5c1ff38fbb'),
    ('24d85424-7d0c-4e18-9034-a7dd917dbdc4','6e5aba48-eeea-4d11-8433-c234f4e56031'),
    ('28b7c819-da59-46cd-be78-94eba4c48e0e','24d85424-7d0c-4e18-9034-a7dd917dbdc4'),
    ('28b7c819-da59-46cd-be78-94eba4c48e0e','63107405-af43-4877-963f-3d0c04bd8955'),
    ('31740ea4-e40b-4aff-b06c-39a8805842a4','0688af08-352f-4a80-972e-467a8c9439e9'),
    ('63107405-af43-4877-963f-3d0c04bd8955','6a44c65a-be52-4381-af7b-cc5a39fdd8d4'),
    ('6a44c65a-be52-4381-af7b-cc5a39fdd8d4','501c542c-37d5-4c06-b454-3e2cafdd0d4f'),
    ('6e5aba48-eeea-4d11-8433-c234f4e56031','b1506711-2c14-4205-9692-0c5bafe6708a'),
    ('77901138-4626-4e5f-867c-cb10a91f784b','daea4761-6811-4ac8-bb2d-1ce3b4546f4c'),
    ('a62ed590-725a-4cd1-b03c-34e8720e3ee3','31740ea4-e40b-4aff-b06c-39a8805842a4'),
    ('d8ca46e9-5665-4d1d-bbc5-ea5c1ff38fbb','77901138-4626-4e5f-867c-cb10a91f784b')
```

Can you support me?

Comment: Support you to do what? You haven't actually asked a (technical) question

Comment: SQL is not designed with variable numbers of columns in mind.  More accurately, the normalised data structure you are Starting with IS the intended pattern, because it can represent the tree with a fixed number rof columns. So, the question arises, WHY do you want to convert away from a SQL pattern, but using SQL to do it?